# Ruby Struct.new doesn't work as expected, it needs extra .new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, struct

I am working on a project and I found an interesting problem. I wanted to use `Struct`. I try to use it like this:

```
> e = Struct.new(:message, :whateve)
=> #<Class:0x007f881dd98b98>
e.message = "something"
NoMethodError: undefined method `message=' for #<Class:0x007f881dd98b98>
from (pry):5:in `__pry__'
```

It works fine if I add it like this: `e = Struct.new(:message, :whateve).new` so I am wondering what is the problem and needs the extra new? I am using ruby 2.2.1p85.

Comment: Defining a struct type (`MyStruct = Struct.new`) isn't the same as initializing an instance of it (`my_struct_obj = MyStruct.new`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens, because `Struct.new(:message, :whateve)` just defines a new class:

```
e = Struct.new(:message, :whateve) # define new class
e.class
#=> Class
e.new #define this class instance
#=> #<struct message=nil, whateve=nil>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes my bad, I was tried to use Struct as an object instead of a structure of creating objects.